# time course heatmap with wave structure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a heat map of a time course data set and cluster the rows like in the plot below. Currently I am using the following code, which does not give a very nice plot. How do I get those characteristic wave structures.

[image]

```
> head(data)
               X0h       X1h       X4h       X9h      X15h      X18h      X21h
gene1         8.117944  8.441725  8.678869  8.152143  8.114986  8.421052  8.054885
gene2         3.655405  4.237245  3.829953  4.160893  4.332883  4.495445  4.550856

pd <- as.data.frame(scale(t(data)))
pd$Time <- sub("_.*", "", rownames(pd))
pd.m <- melt(pd)
pd.m$variable <- as.numeric(factor(pd.m$variable, levels = rev(as.character(unique(pd.m$variable))), ordered=F))

p <- ggplot(pd.m, aes(Time, variable))
p  + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + scale_fill_gradient2(low=muted("blue") +  high=muted("red")) +     scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0h", "0.25h", "0.5h","1h","2h","3h","6h")) + 
 theme_bw(base_size=20) + 
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=12),
                             axis.text.y=element_text(size=12), strip.text.y=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.5, size=12),
                             strip.text.x=element_text(size=12)) + 
 labs(y="Genes", x="Time (h)", fill="")
```

Comment: You are going to need to give an example set of data- use `dput(data[1:40,])` to give us something to work with.